# Openmp nested loop

Tags: c, loops, nested, openmp

just playing around with openmp. Look at this code fragments:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for( i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
        doing something
    }
}
```

and

```
for( i =0;i<n;i++)
{
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
     doing something
  }
}
```

Why is the first one a lot more slower (around the factor 5) than the second one? From theory I thought that the first one must be faster, because the parallel region is only created once and not n-times like the second?
Can someone explain this to me?

The code i want to parallelise has the following structure:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) //wont be parallelizable
{
  for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)  //will be parallelized
  {
    doing sth.
  }

  for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)  //will be parallelized
    for(k = i+1;k<n;k++)
    {
      doing sth.
    }

}
```

I made a simple program to measure the time and reproduce my results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void test( int n)
{
  int i ;
  double t_a = 0.0, t_b = 0.0 ;


  t_a = omp_get_wtime() ;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

    }
  }

  t_b = omp_get_wtime() ;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    }
  }

  printf( "directive outside for-loop: %lf\n", 1000*(omp_get_wtime()-t_a)) ;
  printf( "directive inside for-loop: %lf \n", 1000*(omp_get_wtime()-t_b)) ;
}

int main(void)
{
  int i, n   ;
  double t_1 = 0.0, t_2 = 0.0 ;

  printf( "n: " ) ;
  scanf( "%d", &n ) ;

  t_1 = omp_get_wtime() ;

  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

    }
  }

  t_2 = omp_get_wtime() ;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    }
  }

  printf( "directive outside for-loop: %lf\n", 1000*(omp_get_wtime()-t_1)) ;
  printf( "directive inside for-loop: %lf \n", 1000*(omp_get_wtime()-t_2)) ;

  test(n) ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

If I start it with different n's I always get different results.

```
n: 30000
directive outside for-loop: 0.881884
directive inside for-loop: 0.073054 
directive outside for-loop: 0.049098
directive inside for-loop: 0.011663 

n: 30000
directive outside for-loop: 0.402774
directive inside for-loop: 0.071588 
directive outside for-loop: 0.049168
directive inside for-loop: 0.012013 

n: 30000
directive outside for-loop: 2.198740
directive inside for-loop: 0.065301 
directive outside for-loop: 0.047911
directive inside for-loop: 0.012152 



n: 1000
directive outside for-loop: 0.355841
directive inside for-loop: 0.079480 
directive outside for-loop: 0.013549
directive inside for-loop: 0.012362 

n: 10000
directive outside for-loop: 0.926234
directive inside for-loop: 0.071098 
directive outside for-loop: 0.023536
directive inside for-loop: 0.012222 

n: 10000
directive outside for-loop: 0.354025
directive inside for-loop: 0.073542 
directive outside for-loop: 0.023607
directive inside for-loop: 0.012292
```

How can you explain me this difference?!

Results with your version:

```
Input n: 1000
[2] directive outside for-loop: 0.331396
[2] directive inside for-loop: 0.002864 
[2] directive outside for-loop: 0.011663
[2] directive inside for-loop: 0.001188 
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.021092
[1] directive inside for-loop: 0.001327 
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.005238
[1] directive inside for-loop: 0.001048 
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.020812
[0] directive inside for-loop: 0.001188 
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.005029
[0] directive inside for-loop: 0.001257
```

Comment: You give us far to few information such that we could be helpful. Also, shouldn' the first one just take away one level of `{}` and then be `#pragma omp parallel for` (note the `for` in the pragma) ?

Comment: This for loop should not be parallel! The "doing somehing" part will later contain nested for loops. In my c code the for loop is empty. Its just the question what is the best way to place the openmp directive.

Comment: you did a measure wrong way. not `1000*(omp_get_wtime()-t_1)` but `1000*(t_2-t_1)`.

Comment: My test work so fast on your PC, and you can't measure it so rough. Check update of my answer

Answer (score 5):

> because the parallel region is only created once and not n-times like the second?

Kind of.  The construction

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
}
```

also means allocating work items to threads on '{' and returning threads into thread pool on '}'. It has a lot of thread-to-thread communication. Also, by default waiting threads will go to sleep via OS and some time will be needed for wake thread.

About your middle sample: You can try to limit outer `for`'s parallelity with...

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i,k)
{
for(i=0;i<n;i++) //w'ont be parallelized
{
  #pragma omp for
  for(j=i+1;j<n,j++)  //will be parallelized
  {
    doing sth.
  }
  #pragma omp for    
  for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)  //will be parallelized
    for(k = i+1;k<n;k++)
    {
      doing sth.
    }
  // Is there really nothing? - if no - use:
  // won't be parallelized
  #pragma omp single
  { //seq part of outer loop
      printf("Progress... %i\n", i); fflush(stdout);
  }

  // here is the point. Every thread did parallel run of outer loop, but...
  #pramga omp barrier

  //  all loop iterations are syncronized:
  //       thr0   thr1  thr2
  // i      0      0     0
  //     ----   barrier ----
  // i      1      1     1
  //     ----   barrier ----
  // i      2      2     2
  // and so on
}
}
```

In general, placing parallelity at highest (upper) possible `for` of `for` nest  is better than placing it on inner loops. If you need sequential execution of some code, use the advanced pragmas (like `omp barrier`, `omp master` or `omp single`) or omp_locks for this code. Any of this way will be faster than starting `omp parallel` many times

Comment: Thx for your response. Why do you explicitly declare the variable i as shared? Isnt this by default the case? My whole example given, would you set the openmp directives exactly the way u did in your last post? I want to know what is the common and in general the optimal way.

Comment: Please, reread answer, it was wrong at first verisons. Not. Only iteration variable after `omp for` pragma will be changed in visibility. You can also use c++-styled for: `for(int i=0; i<n;i++);`

Comment: `#pramga omp barrier` inside of the `#pragma omp parallel` is more optimal than `#pragma omp parallel` inside the loop. I have no idea about common method.

Comment: Thx, thats exactly what i remembered from openmp books, but testing this without the inner for loops it is still 5 times slower than the other attempt. The other is nearly as fast as the serial version. Why? I dont get it.

Comment: Biler, what is the `other attempt`? The first code? What `n` did you test? What are running times? Is thread number equal to CPU number? What are they? What is your compiler and compiler version?

Comment: the other attempt is #pragma omp parallel inside the outer for loop. The thread number is equal

Comment: Please look the program code i posted in my question. In my original code I the for loops are in a function and I still get the complementary results.

Answer (score 2):

Your full test is very wrong. You did count time for both parts of code and for second one; not the time of first section. Also, second line of printf did measure time of first printf.

First run is very slow because there is a thread startup time here, memory init and cache effects. Also, the heuristics of omp may be autotuned after several parallel regions

My version of your test:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void test( int n, int j)
{
  int i ;
  double t_a = 0.0, t_b = 0.0, t_c = 0.0 ;
  t_a = omp_get_wtime() ;
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) { }
  }
  t_b = omp_get_wtime() ;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    { }
  }
  t_c = omp_get_wtime() ;
  printf( "[%i] directive outside for-loop: %lf\n", j, 1000*(t_b-t_a)) ;
  printf( "[%i] directive inside for-loop: %lf \n", j, 1000*(t_c-t_b)) ;
}

int main(void)
{
  int i, n, j=3  ;
  double t_1 = 0.0, t_2 = 0.0, t_3 = 0.0;
  printf( "Input n: " ) ;
  scanf( "%d", &n ) ;
  while( j --> 0 ) {
      t_1 = omp_get_wtime();
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) { }
      }

      t_2 = omp_get_wtime();

      for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        #pragma omp parallel
        { }
      }
      t_3 = omp_get_wtime();
      printf( "[%i] directive outside for-loop: %lf\n", j, 1000*(t_2-t_1)) ;
      printf( "[%i] directive inside for-loop: %lf \n", j, 1000*(t_3-t_2)) ;
      test(n,j) ;
  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

I did 3 runs for every n inside the program itself.

Results:

```
$ ./test
Input n: 1000
[2] directive outside for-loop: 5.044824
[2] directive inside for-loop: 48.605116
[2] directive outside for-loop: 0.115031
[2] directive inside for-loop: 1.469195
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.082415
[1] directive inside for-loop: 1.455855
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.081297
[1] directive inside for-loop: 1.462352
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.080528
[0] directive inside for-loop: 1.455786
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.080807
[0] directive inside for-loop: 1.467101
```

Only first run of `test()` is affected. All next results are the same for `test` and `main()`.

Better and more stable results are from such run (I used gcc-4.6.1 and static build)

```
$ OMP_WAIT_POLICY=active GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=0-15 OMP_NUM_THREADS=2  ./test
Input n: 5000
[2] directive outside for-loop: 0.079412
[2] directive inside for-loop: 4.266087
[2] directive outside for-loop: 0.031708
[2] directive inside for-loop: 4.319727
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.047563
[1] directive inside for-loop: 4.290812
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.033733
[1] directive inside for-loop: 4.324406
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.047004
[0] directive inside for-loop: 4.273143
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.092331
[0] directive inside for-loop: 4.279219
```

I did set two omp performance environment variables and limited thread number to 2.

Also. You "paralleled" loop is wrong. (and I reproduced this error in my ^^^ variant) The i variable is shared here:

```
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) { }
      }
```

You should have it as

```
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
        for(int local_i=0;local_i<n;local_i++) { }
      }
```

**UPDATE7** Your result is for n=1000:

```
[2] directive inside for-loop: 0.001188 
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.021092
[1] directive inside for-loop: 0.001327 
[1] directive outside for-loop: 0.005238
[1] directive inside for-loop: 0.001048 
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.020812
[0] directive inside for-loop: 0.001188 
[0] directive outside for-loop: 0.005029
[0] directive inside for-loop: 0.001257
```

the 0.001 or 0.02 output of your code is .... the seconds multiplied by 1000, so it is a millisecond (ms). And it is ... around 1 microsecond or 20 microseconds. The granularity of some system clocks (`user time` or `system time` output fields of `time` utility) are from 1 millisecond, 3 ms or 10 ms. 1 microsecond is 2000-3000 CPU ticks (for 2-3GHz CPU). So you can't measure so short time interval without special setup. You should:

1. disable energy saving of CPU (Intel SpeedStep, AMD ???), which can put CPU in lower-power state by lowering its clock (frequency);
2. disable dynamic overclocking of CPU (Intel turbostep);
3. Measure time without help from OS, e.g. by reading TSC (`rdtsc` asm instruction)
4. Disable instruction reordering on Out-Of-Order CPUs (only atom is not OOO cpu of current generation) before and after `rdtsc`  by adding a `cpuid` instruction  (or other instruction   that will disable reordering)
5. Do the run on completely free system (0% cpu load on both cpu before you will start a test)
6. rewrite test in non-interactive way (don't wait user for input with `scanf`, pass n via `argv[1]`)
7. Don't use Xserver and slow terminal to output the results
8. Make interrupts number lower (turn off network, physically; don't play a film in background, don't touch mouse and keyboard)
9. Do a lot of runs (I mean not program restarting, but restarting of measured part of program; j=100 in my program) and add statistic calculation over results.
10. Don't run a printf so often (between measures); it will pollute the caches and TLB. Store results internally and output them after all measurements are done.

**UPDATE8:** As statistical I mean: take several values, 7 or more. Discard first value (or even 2-3 first values if you has high number of values measured). Sort them. Discard ... 10-20 % of maximum and minimum results. Calculate the mean. Literally

```
double results[100], sum=0.0, mean = 0.0;
int count = 0;
// sort results[5]..results[100] here
for(it=20; it< 85; it ++) {
  count++; sum+= results[it];
}
mean = sum/count;
```

Comment: wow thanks for fast and detailed answer! Oh, yeah the time measurement was crap....should ve noticed that. Im using gcc 4.4.5. So, when you initialize the i variable in the for loop, its not shared? And Im even with your version getting complementary results and I dont know why. Look at the main question for the results. I do have a dual core processor in this machine!

Comment: try to make j bigger and rerun. Yes, if you write `int i; \n #pragma omp parallel \n {for(i...)}` - the i will be shared. If you will write `int i; \n #pragma omp parallel for \n {for(i...)}` (note for in pragma), i will be private. Your time measuring is bad because you try to measure very short (fast) parts of code with not-so-exact system call. Also you did not any statistical manipulation on noisy results.

Comment: Misunderstanding...its clear that with for in pragma the loop variable will be private. I meant your correction for(int local_i=0;local_i<n;local_i++) Dont see the difference there and isnt it bad c programming style to initialize the variables where you need them? I made j=20 and it converged....still no change. Please explain me the possible statistical maniplulations and what are noisy results?

Comment: `OMP FOR` or `OMP PARALLEL FOR` will change  iterator to `private`; `OMP PARALLEL` will not. Citing OpenMP 3.0 "2.5.1 Loop Construct" page 39, lines 29-30: "If this variable would otherwise be shared, it is implicitly made private in the loop construct.". Loop construct is (page 38, line 11) "`#pragma omp for`". Pragma `Omp parallel` will not change any variable to private (section 2.4 of the standard).